# Web service running on IIS cant access password protected folder on Linux machine

Tags: asp.net

I am running a Web Service on a Windows XP pc and my goal is this service to access a folder located in the network (Samba Server) on a Linux machine.

The error that I am getting from the browser is  "path format is not valid".

This means that IIS can't recognize  the path at all.

My question is, whether this is a problem due to the password protection of the folder or  is it a compatibility issue between IIS and Linux?

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you granted access to the Samba share to some user ID - but which user ID?

The user under which an ASP.NET application runs is likely a machine account.  Check your IIS settings for the name of that account.